# Why is this an infinite loop? For Loop with long int as the data type

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I get this error in Visual Studio:

> C6295 Ill-defined for-loop.  Loop executes infinitely.

```cpp
 for (long int i = 1; i <= 5000000000; i++) {
        //cout << i;
    }
```

Comment: What is max long int on your platform? Is it less the value in your loop condition?

Comment: On Visual C++ `long` is only 32bits wide, so the largest value it can represent is `2147483647`. Trying to increment beyond that is signed integer overflow and therefore causes undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm just learning c++, so I don't know the answer to that. How do I find out?

Comment: Check with ```std::numeric_limits<long int>::max()``` to see the maximum value of ```long int```. It will never reach 5000000000 if the maximum value is 2147483647. In this case you will need ```int64_t i=1```.

Comment: See C++ [data models](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Data_models).

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I figured it out from the help I received here. I changed it to int64_t and it works fine.

```
for (int64_t i = 1; i <= 5000000000; i++) {
    //cout << i;
}
```

Comment: `long long` would work, too.

Comment: Pete - You are correct. long long works, but I simplified it with int64_t as sxu suggested.

Comment: It’s unlikely, but `std::int64_t` might not exist. If you don’t need exact sizes don’t use them.